# What's the best policy for managing Knowledge Article Data Categories?

Tags: profile, articles, roles

We need to begin controlling Knowledge Articles by Data Category.  Anyone have experience on using Roles vs. Profiles?  Our idea is to strip access from Roles and provide access via the Profile settings.  Any pitfalls?